# How to override an imported predicate?

Tags: nixos, nix

Consider a `/etc/nixos/root.nix` containing the following:

```
{
  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg:
    builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
      "foo"
    ];
}
```

This configuration is imported into `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, which provides its own `allowUnfreePredicate`:

```
{
  imports = [
    /etc/nixos/root.nix
  ];

  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg:
    builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
      "bar"
    ];
}
```

In this case, only `pkgs.bar` can be installed, because the last predicate overrides the first one. **Is there some way to combine them,** especially considering `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` shouldn't "know" whether any of its imports are specifying this predicate?

Update: [Reported upstream](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/197325) in the hopes that it might be fixed there.

Comment: Ideally, these predicates should be composed with logical OR. This seems like an obvious oversight; I'd open an issue in Nixpkgs about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but is rather complicated:

```
{
  config,
  lib,
  modulesPath,
  pkgs,
  specialArgs,
  options,
}: let
  imports = [
    /etc/nixos/cachix.nix
    /etc/nixos/root.nix
  ];
in {
  inherit imports;

  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg:
    (builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
      "bar"
    ])
    || builtins.any (
      path: let
        package = import path {
          inherit config lib modulesPath pkgs specialArgs options;
        };
      in
        if builtins.hasAttr "nixpkgs" package
        then package.nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate pkg
        else false
    )
    imports;
}
```

Basically:

1. Pull out `imports` so it can be referenced without creating a `rec`ursive set.
2. For each import, check whether it has `nixpkgs` (I've included the cachix configuration, since that doesn't have `nixpkgs`), and if so, whether its `allowUnfreePredicate` is true for the package.
3. If any of the imported `allowUnfreePredicate`s are true, allow installing the package.

Hopefully there's a simpler way to do this.